# Spring Cloud Stream - custom subscription name

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

The documentation says if you want to use a pre-configured subscription name it must be a combination of topic name and custom group name:

```
If you are manually creating Pub/Sub subscriptions for consumers, make sure that they follow 
the naming convention of <destinationName>.<consumerGroup>.
```

Seems like a limitation for some cases - is there a way to use an arbitrary name instead?

Comment: Which documentation you are referring to? This naming convention specifically applies to Rabbit binder to ensure its internal routing mechanism can be relied upon to support consumer groups which are not natively supported in Rabbit. What would you want the name to be?

Comment: From here: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/multi/multi__spring_cloud_stream.html

Comment: I want the name to be anything - basically we have many topics in google pubsub, asking them to be renamed to the pattern is not easy...

Comment: Looks like the same naming convention for gcp pubsub: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/72d746486fedd19b16ead3cdbbcfb48c3e90c3a9/spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gcp/stream/binder/pubsub/provisioning/PubSubChannelProvisioner.java#L77